# PHP create associative array from list($key, $value)

Tags: php, arrays, list, explode

I have an array that has resulted from an explode() function. 
The final operation I need to do is to separate each element 
based on an internal delimeter and load it all into an associative array.
Something sort of like the following, which gets me the output ...
but I can't figure out how to get my results into an array.
Help please?

```
$string = 
item1:val1\n
item2:val2\n
item3:val3\n
item4:val4\n

$exploded = explode("\n",$string);
foreach($exploded as $iteration) {
list($key, $value) = explode(":",$iteration);
}
```

Comment: You take `$key` and `$value` and put them into an array.

Comment: How about declaring array variable before loop, then assigning $arr[$key] = $value; inside loop?

Answer (score 1):

Just build the array with the `$key` and `$value`:

```
$exploded = explode("\n",$string);
foreach($exploded as $iteration) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(":",$iteration);
    $result[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Please don't answer such questions, they deserve only simple hint and a close vote.